# JBoss extremely slow in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jboss

**Problem:** In Eclipse, you start JBoss in debug mode. Initially, everything works fine. After a while the server gets extremely slow and it takes eternities to step through your code. Restarts of either Eclipse or JBoss won't help.

This drove me mad, so I want to share my solution with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:** Delete (or disable) all your breakpoints. In Eclipse, go to *Window* -> *Show View* -> *Breakpoints*, select all entries and remove them. Afterwards, debugging will run flawlessly again.

Now you can set those breakpoints again that you really need.